# Is there any way I can block an integer from changing its value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to make an integer value locked in place so that trying to edit it (`i += 1`) has no effect? Example:

```
i = 0

while i < 10:
    i += 1

if i == 10:
    #lock the integer
```

I have a problem with this because if the value goes over a limit the program crashes. I could use try except but it would be better to somehow stop the exception from happening in the first place. Any help appreciated :).

Comment: Why wouldn't you just code it so it can't be set over 10? "Locking" it feels like a band-aid for some fundamental issues with your code or chosen variable types.

Comment: This really feels like an XY-problem. Why don't try to ask about X which is what you're trying to do and not about Y which is ***how*** you're trying to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `break` statement inside an `if` statement, inside the `while` loop. For example:

```py
i = 0
while True:
    if i == 10:
        break
    i += 1
```

Once `i` contains the integer value `10`, the program will exit the `while` loop, at the `break` statement. Not really "locking", but it will prevent `i` from exceeding a given limit.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for